# Is there a way to do the following with f-strings in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Currently, if I wanted to format a string and display a variable number of {}s, I would probably write something like:

```
data = [1, 2, 3]

print(("It's as easy as {}" + ((len(data)-1)*", {}")).format(*data))
```

I'd like to figure out how to do this with f-strings, but:

```
print(f"It's as easy as {data[0]}" + ((len(data)-1)*", {*data}"))
```

gives me:

```
It's as easy as 1, {*data}, {*data}, {*data}
```

I'm fairly new to Python. Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: `', '.join(map(str, data))` would have been easier than building a dynamic format string.

Comment: The reason you get what you get is because your first string is an f-string and the second string is a normal string (composed of (Len(data-1)) instances of the static string "{*data}". Your 2nd string isn't an f-string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some strategy using `str.join()` is probably your best bet.  Something like

```
f"It's as easy as {', '.join(map(str, data))}"
```

That's a little clunky though.  I would probably write a seperate function for cleaner code

```
def commas(l):
    return ', '.join(map(str, data))

print(f"It's as easy as {commas(data)}")
# It's as easy as 1, 2, 3
```